# Working out minimum of matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Basic linear algebra question. I am following some notes which goes directly from 
$$q(\gamma)=\inf_x\left[{1\over2}X^TDX+c^TX+\gamma^T(A^TX-b)\right]$$
to
$$={1\over2}(\gamma^TA^T+c^T)D^{-1}(A\gamma+c)-b^T\gamma$$

where D is symmetric positive definite.
I am getting stuck making the leap so if anyone could point out where I am going off track, I would greatly appreciate it.

$${\partial\over\partial X}=X^TD+c^T+\gamma^TA^T=0$$
$$X^TD=-c^T-\gamma^TA^T$$
$$X^T=-c^TD^{-1}-\gamma^TA^TD^{-1}$$ and
$$X=-D^{-1}c-D^{-1}A\gamma$$
Substituting back 
$$q(\gamma)={1\over2}(-c^TD^{-1}-\gamma^TA^TD^{-1})D(-D^{-1}c-D^{-1}A\gamma)+c^T(-D^{-1}c-D^{-1}A\gamma)+\gamma^T(A^T(-D^{-1}c-D^{-1}A\gamma)-b)$$
$${1\over2}(\gamma^TA^T+c^T)D^{-1}(A\gamma+c)-c^TD^{-1}c-c^TD^{-1}A\gamma-\gamma^TA^TD^{-1}c-\gamma^TA^TD^{-1}A\gamma-\gamma^Tb$$
and this is where I get stuck. I don't see how
$$-c^TD^{-1}c-c^TD^{-1}A\gamma-\gamma^TA^TD^{-1}c-\gamma^TA^TD^{-1}A\gamma$$
goes away.

Thanks for any pointers.